# Kafka Consumer commitSync(offsets) does not work when invoked during partition revoke in a rebalance

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am completely baffled at a behaviour I am seeing and wondering why this might be manifesting.
I have the following components :

Kafka Consumer

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootStrapServer);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, StickyAssignor.class.getName());
return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

On rebalance occurring due to a new consumer joining the group :

```
@Override
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    log.info("Rebalance occurring, partitions revoked: {}", partitions);
    stopAllWorkGracefully();
    commitOffsets();
  }

private void commitOffsets(){

  //Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> toCommit
  try{
    consumer.commitSync(toCommit);
    log.info("Commit complete");
  }catch (Exception e){
    log.error("Error while committing", e);
    retry.set(true);
  }
```

}

I can clearly see in the logs the log line for "Commit Complete" however the offsets do not get committed on the kafka topic and after the new partitions get assigned the same messages for which the commit was made are getting picked up again.
Am I misunderstanding something here ? Isn't commit during partitions revoke an expected mechanism ?